# NSOperationQueue is performing on the main thread on ios4 and not on io5?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, nsoperationqueue

Is there any reason why an NSOperationQueue is performing on the main thread on ios 4.2.1 and runing on a seperate thread (as expected) on ios 5.0.1.

I'm using an NSOperationQueue to perfom a busy operation on a big amount of pictures (ALassets) on the launch of my app but it's runing on the main thread on ios4 and not on ios5...

Here is a piece of code

from the main thread :

```
    cacheManager = [[PicturesCacheManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    //start the generation of the pictures array
    NSLOG(@"setUpToDatePicturesArray");
    operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [operationQueue addOperation:cacheManager];
    [cacheManager release];
```

From PictureCacheManager :

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id <CachePicturesProtocol> )delegatePic
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        [self setDelegate:delegatePic];
    }

return self;
} 

-(void)main{
    [self loadCurrentCameraRoll]; //do lot of stuff 
}

-(void)loadCurrentCameraRoll{
//NSLOG(@"loadCurrentCameraRoll");
// photos
void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    //photos only!
    if(result != NULL && [[result valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyType"] isEqualToString:@"ALAssetTypePhoto"]) {

        //Do stuff
    }
};

void (^assetGroupEnumerator)( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {
        NSLOG(@"current group = %@", group);
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }
    else{
        //we've enumerated all the groups

    }
};

assetsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                         NSLOG(@"Failure : %@", [error description]);
                     }];

}
```

UPDATE : It seems that the matter comes from the enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock: method. 
Before I call it I'm actually in a seperate thread but after it goes thru it switches to the main thread...

Comment: You guess wrong.  Please post the code where you create the queue and add the operation to it.

Comment: ok here is some code. Basically loadCurrentCameraRoll scan the cameraRoll and save thumbnails in a local directory

Comment: Do you overide -isConcurrent ?

Comment: Try logging the value of `[NSThread isMainThread]` in your `main` method,just to confirm it is running on the main thread.  Is it possible a secondary thread is starting but performing synchronous tasks on the main thread (e.g. UI updates).

Comment: Ok I tried and I confirm it's running on the main thread

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> In iOS, operation queues do not use Grand Central Dispatch to execute
>   operations. **They create separate threads** for non-concurrent operations
>   and launch concurrent operations from the current thread. For a
>   discussion of the difference between concurrent and non-concurrent
>   operations and how they are executed, see NSOperation Class Reference.

So, NSOperationQueue always performs on a separate thread

Comment: Yep I know that, and that's why I don't understand why it's not runing on a separate thread on the device with ios 4.2.1. I added this piece of code in my nsoperation and I can see the log message on ios4 and not on ios5
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
            NSLOG(@"isMainThread");
        }
Also the mainThread is totaly locked on ios4 due to the images processing, not on ios5....

Comment: This isn't correct - or at least when you posted it, the documentation  was out of date. In iOS 4 and later, operation queues use Grand Central Dispatch to execute operations. Prior to iOS 4, they create separate threads for non-concurrent operations and launch concurrent operations from the current thread.